# Not able to run grunt-karma from jenkins

Tags: angularjs, jenkins, gruntjs

I am using Grunt-karma to launch my angular unit test .When i preform the task on command prompt it is working fine but when i configure the same jenkins is not able to open firefox window .Can anybody tell me what is the issue .Below is my config files

--karma config

```
basePath = '../';

files = [
  MOCHA,
  MOCHA_ADAPTER,
  'test/lib/angular/chai.js',
  'Scripts/angular.js',
  'Scripts/angular-*.js',
  'test/lib/angular/angular-mocks.js',
  'Scripts/ControllerForTest.js',
  'Scripts/ControllerForTestModule.js',
  'Scripts/LogLoader.js',
  'Scripts/App.js',
  'test/unit/**/*.js'
];

autoWatch = false;
singleRun = true;

browsers = ['Firefox'];

junitReporter = {
  outputFile: 'test_out/unit.xml',
  suite: 'unit'
};
```

Grunt Task --

```
karma: {
            unit: {
                configFile: 'config/karma.conf.js'
            }
        },
```

Jenkins Log --

```
E:\MedicineShopInvetory\MedicineShopInventory\MedicineShopInventory>grunt
[4mRunning "clean:src" (clean) task[24m
Cleaning "release"...[32mOK[39m

[4mRunning "uglify:dist" (uglify) task[24m
File "release/app.min.js" created.

[4mRunning "cssmin:minify" (cssmin) task[24m
File release/Doc.min.css created.

[4mRunning "karma:unit" (karma) task[24m
[32mINFO [karma]: [39mKarma server started at http://localhost:9876/
[32mINFO [launcher]: [39mStarting browser Firefox
[33mWARN [launcher]: [39mFirefox have not captured in 60000 ms, killing.
[32mINFO [launcher]: [39mTrying to start Firefox again.
```

Answer (score 0):

How are you running Jenkins? If you're running it on a headless server, it's possible you never started a headless display like xvfb, and if you have, it could be that you haven't exported the display.